# Parse fetched hashtags and create "svelte-routing" links

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm fetching dynamic content from server that can include a hashtag:

> {content:" text text #Cup "}

Doing:

```
<script>
  import { link } from "svelte-routing"
    
    function hash(text) {
      return text.replace(/\#Cup/, '<a href="cup" use:link>Cup</a>')
  }
</script>

<p>
    {hash("this is a #Cup")}
</p>
<p>
    {@html hash("this is a #Cup")}
</p>
```

Second way will render it as is (without being connected to svelte-routing actions or events).

How do i turn into into "svelte-routing" 'use:link' element?
(or working `<Link to={cup}/>`)

**EDIT:**
I changed best answer to @pushkine.
The reason is that it requires less string sanitization while preserving ability to link to hashtags when using like so:

```
 {first}
    {#each arr as { href, str }}
        <a href={href.toLowerCase()} use:link>{href}</a>
        {str}
    {/each}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<script>
    import { link } from 'svelte-routing';
    let str = 'this is a #Cup';
    const [first, ...arr] = str.split(/\#/g).map((v, i) => {
        if (i === 0) return v;
        else {
            const index = v.indexOf(' ');
            return { href: index !== -1 ? v.slice(0, index + 1) : v, str: index !== -1 ? v.slice(index) : '' };
        }
    });
</script>

<p>
    {@html first}
    {#each arr as { href, str }}
        <a href={href.toLowerCase()} use:link>{href}</a>
        {@html str}
    {/each}
</p>
```

Comment: It took me a moment to figure out how it works. This is exact answer to my question, i accepted other b/c of its 
 brevity but thank you for posting it.

Comment: If you could add an explanation of how your answer works it would make it a better quality answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `links` action instead of the `link` action.

```html
<script>
  import { links } from "svelte-routing"

  const hashtags = text => text.replace(/(#([\w]+))/g, '<a href="/tags/$2">$1</a>');
</script>

<p use:links>
    {@html hashtags("this is #just a #Cup")}
</p>
```

Keep in mind, that this string is not escaped. So inserting html tags and executing XSS attacks is possible with this solution.

Comment: I think that using more specific regex `/#([a-z0-9]+)/gi` would mitigate XSS. Thanks of answer.

Comment: @Mike The XSS can be anywhere in `text`.

Comment: yes i realized that. So one   would have to either sanitize string displayed or go string splitting method like pushkine

Answer (score 2):

svelte-routing has a `use:links` action you can add to the parent container:

```html
<script>
  import { links } from "svelte-routing"
        
  function hash(text) {
      return text.replace(/\#Cup/, '<a href="cup">Cup</a>')
  }
</script>
    
<p use:links>
    {@html hash("this is a #Cup")}
</p>
```